# Teacher assistant or assistant teacher?

Tags: adjectives, nouns, word-order

How to describe in two words someone who helped a teacher in some way, but was under its command? An assistant teacher, or a teacher assistant?

I'm not talking about a precise teacher (so not a proper name), but only the hierarchy position.

I know the adjective must be before the noun, but which one is considered as a noun and which one as an adjective here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends very much on the exact context.

An assistant teacher would usually be someone who is a teacher, but maybe only works part-time.

On the other hand a teacher assistant (which I don't think I've ever heard used) would be somone who's an assistant by job and assists teachers. For example this could be a specialized assistant for disabled students.

Now the usual word I would expect for somone who shoulders part of the teaching burden, but usually is not the main teacher for a lecture would be a teaching assistant. This is a standard position in US (and I believe many other) universities which is overwhelmingly staffed by graduate students and whose main role is to run labs or study groups, grade papers, collect and grade homework and hold office hours.

Comment: So I was in fact looking for teaching assistant. I just didn't even think to it. Thanks you for this idea that I didn't have !